# Beautify only selected code in ace editor

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I'm using the ace editor in javascript and I want to make a shortcut that beautifies the selected code (and ***ONLY*** the selected code). Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically your beautify function would be external to Ace; most editing packages use js-beautify or something else. So the exact answer depends on your specific setup. To implement it:

```
var selectedText = editor.getCopyText();
var range = editor.selection.getRange();
var beautifiedText = yourBeautifyFunction(selectedText);
editor.getSession().replace(range,beautifiedText);
```